# why i cant login this site using python in a post method

Tags: python, authentication, urllib2, cookielib

this is my code to login  a site using python :

```
import urllib2, cookielib
cookie_support= urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookielib.CookieJar())
opener = urllib2.build_opener(cookie_support, urllib2.HTTPHandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
content = urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.1.200/order/index.php?op=Login&ac=login&userName=%E8%B5%B5%E6%B1%9F%E6%98%8E&userPwd=123').read()

print content
```

it show :

```
{"title":"login error","body":"username or password error","data":{"status":1}}
```

but the username and password is right , i can login this site using firefox ,

so  what can i do ,

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a GET request. To make a POST request, use:

```
content = urllib2.urlopen(
    'http://192.168.1.200/order/index.php",
    'op=Login&ac=login&userName=%E8%B5%B5%E6%B1%9F%E6%98%8E&userPwd=123').read()
```

The `urlopen` method sends a POST request if data (second argument) is passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a password manager:

from [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml):

```
# create a password manager
password_mgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()

# Add the username and password.
# If we knew the realm, we could use it instead of ``None``.
top_level_url = "http://example.com/foo/"
password_mgr.add_password(None, top_level_url, username, password)

handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)

# create "opener" (OpenerDirector instance)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)

# use the opener to fetch a URL
opener.open(a_url)

# Install the opener.
# Now all calls to urllib2.urlopen use our opener.
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```